# Calculation of integral by parts

Tags: integration

I have to calculate this integral:
$$\int x^4\sin(2x)dx$$

And I have question. Is it necessary to calculate it using $4x$ by parts method (brute force), or is there some more elegant process?

Thx a lot

Comment: Use integration by parts three times. I don't think there's a more elegant way.

Comment: well, it is a task from hell then :-D, so long

Comment: You can use tabular integration, also known as the "Stand and Deliver" method, to keep track of things a bit more efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{d(x^n\cos ax)}{dx}=-ax^n\sin ax+nx^{n-1}\cos(ax)$$

Integrate both sides with respect to $x,$

$$aI(n)=-x^n\cos ax+nJ(n-1)$$

Similarly $$aJ(m)=x^m\sin ax-mI(m-1)$$

where $$I(n)=\int x^n\sin ax\ dx,J(n)=\int x^n\cos(ax)$$